# How do you add multiple rows to a manually created ADODB.Recordset in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, adodb, recordset

I am trying to create a new C#.Net COM+ app to communicate with legacy VB6 apps. So far I have everything working I can return all sorts of objects including an ADODB.Recordset.

However I can only add one row of data to that Recordset and if I try to add extra rows only the last row is actually returned to the VB6 app.

```
// List of data
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Fred", "John", "Jane" };

// Create ADODB Recordset
var adors = new ADODB.Recordset();
adors.Fields.Append("name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, 250, FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable);
adors.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);

// Loop through data and add a row for each one
foreach (var name in names)
{
    adors.AddNew();
    adors.Fields["name"].Value = name;
    adors.Update(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
}

// Return Recordset
return adors;
```

For the above example the VB6 would receive a Recordset back with 1 row of data which would be "Jane"

Could someone please explain to me how to add multiple rows to an ADODB.Recordset in C#?

Comment: adors.Fields["name"].Value = membership.MemberNumber; Are you sure that this statement is correct? You are not actually assigning the name to the ADODB recordset.

Comment: @Thangadurai no this was incorrect. Please see my latest update. That was some of the real code getting into the example. I have also found an answer to my question which I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more playing around and I was able to find an answer. You need to set the Recordsets AbsolutePosition to 1.

```
// Set recordset back to starting position
adors.AbsolutePosition = (PositionEnum)1;
```

Full example below

```
// List of data
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Fred", "John", "Jane" };

// Create ADODB Recordset
var adors = new ADODB.Recordset();
adors.Fields.Append("name", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, 250, FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable);
adors.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);

// Loop through data and add a row for each one
foreach (var name in names)
{
    adors.AddNew();
    adors.Fields["name"].Value = name;
    adors.Update(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
}

// Set recordset back to starting position
adors.AbsolutePosition = (PositionEnum)1;

// Return Recordset
return adors;
```